# Generating primes with floor of a polynomial $[p(n)]$

Tags: number-theory

Is there a polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients and degree at least one such that $[p(n)]$ is prime for every natural number $n$? If yes, what is such a polynomial $p(x)$ and if no, how to prove?

Comment: Sure, $p(x)=7.45627527$ :-) I will give a serious answer too. (If I manage to come up with one.)

Comment: ha ha! i edited the problem that the polynomial should is'nt from degree zero.

Comment: https://www.sonoma.edu/math/colloq/primes_sonoma_state_9_24_08.pdf

Comment: @JackYoon That doesn't actually answer _this_ question at all.

Comment: I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if the answer was yes; you can encode a _lot_ of information into a real number, let alone several.  You can show that $p()$ can't be linear either (there are arbitrarily large gaps between primes but the gaps between $p(n)$ and $p(n+1)$ are bounded for $p()$ of degree one) so the minimum possible degree is two, but beyond that I can't see any good argument one way or the other.  This may well be an open problem.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ok I was clearly careless. Having thought a bit more about it I'm sure no one ever found such $p(x)$ as if it were found, the question about 'largest prime ever found' would be meaningless.

Comment: @JackYoon No more so than Mills' Constant ( http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MillsConstant.html ) makes the question meaningless; it's very plausible that one could have an existence proof for such a polynomial and even an 'explicit' formula similar to Mills', but that calculating its coefficients to sufficient accuracy requires more effort than the primality testing itself.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/196191/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Mohammad Ghiasi below.

> With Vesselin's idea in the comments proof is ready as below:
>
> If $p(x)-p(0) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ then the problem isn't so hard.
>
> If $p(x)-p(0) \not \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ then there is an irrational coefficient for a term of degree bigger than or equal one. There is a problem in ergodic theory that says that the sequence $p(n) \text{ mod 1}$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$. It can prove similarly that the sequence $p(n) \text{ mod 2}$ is equidistributed in $[0,2)$, and with this observation we find that there are a lot of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that for them $[p(n)]$ is even and thus isn't prime.
>
> Also with the equidistributivity of $p(n) \text{ mod m}$ in $[0,m)$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ we find that natural density of
>
> $$\{n\ |\ m\ |[p(n)]\}$$
>
> is $\frac{1}{m}$.